# MySql to MS Access query conversion

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a mysql query, which I want to use in MS Access.

```
SELECT company_name, agent_id FROM
( SELECT company_name, agent_id, @rn := IF(@prev = agent_id, @rn + 1, 1) 
  AS rn, @prev := agent_id FROM users 
  JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars 
  ORDER BY agent_id DESC, company_name)
 AS T1 
 WHERE T1.agent_id is not null and  rn <= 3;
```

I have been trying to run it in Access but its throwing the error: "Syntax error in from clause".

Comment: Does Access support the @ syntax?

Comment: I recommend You to forget that this task was solved in MySQL - the difference is too great for the solution can be adapted. Show MS Access source data store format. Describe what exactly you want to receive from that data in that data structure (the sample of source data and result You need on that source is safe).

Comment: Face it.  All databases have quite different syntax.  Even if it had @-syntax, something else would probably cause trouble.  For example, I think column names have brackets around them.  Or start from scratch.  Do you even know what the query is trying to do?

Comment: If you can use the data from MySQL Server tables (link them to Ms Access using ODBC) , you can do a passthrough query, which get excuted on the server.